# Changing between the generated diagrams txtUML

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus, txtuml

I am trying to generate multiple class and state machine diagrams using txtUML software in Eclipse. After [adding multiple txtUML diagram descriptions-(see picture1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqL3c.png) in order to generate them, it seems everything is going fine.

My problem is that after everything is [finished successfully (see picture2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6veSS.png) I just see one of the diagrams and I can not see the other diagram.

I am using :

> MacBook Pro - Mac OS Sierra version 10.12 (16A323)
>
> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After adding multiple txtUML diagram descriptions-(see picture1) in order to generate them, it seems everything is going fine.

If there was no error message during the generation of diagrams then indeed, the diagrams were generated without issues.

As to your issue, you can switch the diagrams from the panel right below your current diagram. I have highlighted the panel I am talking about in your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI965.png).

There are three tabs in the panel in the image you provided and it corresponds to the three diagrams you were generating.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Aliamonda, I was just focusing on the upside tabs..!! I never noticed that there is tabs on downside as well..!!! now I can easily switch between the diagram